# Inset child views in a subclass of ViewGroup without rewriting the onLayout() implementation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

**THE CONTEXT**

I'm trying to create a custom view that extends the `LinearLayout`. In short, this view draws its own background by overriding `View.onDraw()` method. The background has a shadow around it (much like the `CardView`).

**THE OBJECTIVE**

Since the background is like the card view with a shadow, child views should not be allowed to fill in the entire view. Fixed *padding* should be left for the shadows around the card. This padding should not be effected the padding set by the xml padding attribute or `setPadding()` methods. Its something akin to the `CardView`'s `setContentPadding()` method.

**THE APPROACH**

I'm trying the achieve this by overriding the `onLayout()` method of the `LinearLayout`. The official documentation says:

> Called from layout when this view should assign a size and position to each of its children. Derived classes with children should override this method and call layout on each of their children.

The `LinearLayout`'s implementation of the `onLayout()` works well work my case. So don't want to rewrite the the entire implementation. Thus I tried to achieve this by overriding the `onLayout()` method in my custom class and changing the arguments passed to super to account for the shadow as shown below:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(
            changed,
            left + shadowSize,
            top + shadowSize,
            right - shadowSize,
            bottom - shadowSize
    );
}
```

**THE PROBLEM**

The problem, however, is that this has no effect on the `LinearLayout`'s children. No matter what values I pass to super, the child views remain the same.

**THE QUESTION**

Why is this not working? Or rather whats the best approach to achieve a content inset/padding for classes such as the `LinearLayout` that already have an `onLayout()` implementation that I don't want to modify or rewrite?

Comment: i'm not 100% sure but you could try applying your logic to `onLayout`'s brother: `onMeasure`

Comment: @pskink onMeasure would restrict the space I have for the background as well. I want  the background to take up the entire space and only inset the child views.

Comment: ah ok forget what i said before, but cannot you just increase the 4 internal paddings with your values?

Comment: @pskink If I do that, anytime the user sets a padding, the content inset would replaced with the padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because width and height are attributes which provide information for the parent of the View. Anything that starts with layout_ is an instruction to the parent.
In your case, onLayout you are supposed to layout the children of the ViewGroup, not change the dimensions of the current view. In onMeasure is where you measure the children. And onLayout is where you position them. You CAN indent all the children if you want in onLayout but you can't do it if you're calling the parent. 
[This post may help understand build custom ViewGroup](https://medium.com/android-news/perfmatters-building-a-custom-viewgroup-part-3-165dae1bb5ff#.d4lqufp3i%EF%BB%BF)
What I recommend is that you extend ViewGroup and have only one child in the custom ViewGroup, then layout the child to the same size as your custom view group while adjusting for the shadow. This will allow you to set a shadow on your custom ViewGroup while avoiding the issue of drawing outside the bounds. This is the easiest approach. you could layout each child if you want. Also, if using the new ConstraintsLayout is an option, that may help prevent having to use a custom ViewGroup.

Comment: I've been looking at source codes for the past hours. Yes, all signs point to this direction. Thanks for confirming it!